# Creating a WebSocket Clock

Tags: c#, websocket

For school project reasons I would like to create a WebSocket based clock (hello world kind of thing), where the user would go to my website and it would only display a clock running, except that the current-server-time would not be "retrived" via javascript or anything like that, but "pushed"! Where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement the server in C#, the first decision you'll probably have to make which WebSocket framework to use. One of those is [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/).

If you are undecided about server-side language, and like Python, you could checkout [this](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/websocket/broadcast) example. It sends out a tick message every second to all connected WebSocket clients (JavaScript included) - it'll also broadcast any messages received from a client to all the others.